# Correct reporting of percentages comparisons

Tags: percentage, reporting

I am struggling to find a clear answer somewhere else. So, when we have two percentage values, what are correct ways to compare these and formulate the comparison in a report?

```
A = 75%
B = 50%
```

1. For the **absolute** difference of A and B (`75% - 50% = 25%`):

- *"A is 25% higher than B"*
- *"A is higher than B by 25%"*
- *"A is higher than B by 25 percentage points"*
- *"A has 25 percentage points more than B"*

2. For the **relative** difference of A and B (`(75% - 50%) / 50% = 0.5`):

- *"A is 50% higher than B"*
- *"A is higher than B by 50%"*
- *"A is higher than B by 50 percentage points"*
- <s>*"A has 50 percentage points more than B"*</s> (I don't think this is correct)

Comment: These all tell the same story.

Comment: This is indeed an issue. In many contexts, it is customary to use "points" instead of "%" to speak about the absolute difference, so as to avoid confusion with the relative difference. For instance, in a presidential election, if candidate A got 52.5% and candidate B got 47.5%, then we don't say "candidate A got 5% more votes than candidate B", which would sound like a relative difference, but instead "candidate A got 5 more points than candidate B", even though no one bothered to define the word "point" before using it.

Comment: @user2974951 that would imply that saying both "A is 25% higher than B" and "A is 50% higher than B" is correct which leaves space for confusion between reporting absolute and relative differences. For example "A is 50% higher than B" could then also mean `A=100%, B=50%`. I would love to not step into that situation when reporting.

Comment: Percentages on percentages often confuse.  You could say "$75\%$ is $25$ percentage points more than $50\%$" or say "$75\%$ is $1.5$ times $50\%$" and be more likely to be understood